# Conditional definition of a environment

Tags: environments, page-breaking, minipage

Is it possible to have defintion of an environment based of the value of a string. I have a common preamble file which works for a large number of different documents. Depending on the nature of the document, I would like the environment to be defined slightly differently. In effect I am asking for overloading an environment definition.

To be specific, I have a environment called `partx` which I want to be printed as a single block in some documents whereas in some other it should be flow-able. The single-block I have implemented as a `minipage`. I want the other one to be free of `minipage` so that it can straddle across pages.

Can I *overload* environment?

This MWE shows ::

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% one of these is to be commented out to be able to select the approproiate partx from 
% an included file which serves as a common preamble
\newcommand{\doctype}{unbrokenpartx}
%\newcommand{\doctype}{breakblepartx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% this part is in a seperate file, a common preamble
\newenvironment{partx}{
    \noindent\minipage{\textwidth} % ideally this directive should be conditional on \doctype
    % some stuff goes here
}{
    % some other stuff goes here
    \endminipage
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \begin{partx}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{partx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might have a look at `\ifdefstring` in the `etoolbox` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing what you want could be done in different ways, you could either check the condition and define the environment accordingly (the test would be done only once, but it wouldn't be as dynamic, you couldn't change mid-document without copying the definition). The following does so. Note that I use `\ifdefstring` but the generated macro is defined in a way that it needs a `\fi` after the conditional stuff. That has the advantages of allowing possible category code changes and other stuff in the test.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%\newcommand*\doctype{unbrokenpartx}
\newcommand*\doctype{breakablepartx}

\newcommand\ifdoctype[1]
  {%
    \ifdefstring{\doctype}{#1}{\iftrue}{\iffalse}%
  }
\ifdoctype{unbrokenpartx}
  \newenvironment{partx}
    {%
      \noindent\minipage{\textwidth}%
      % some stuff goes here
      \ignorespaces
    }
    {%
      % some other stuff goes here
      \endminipage
    }
\fi
\ifdoctype{breakablepartx}
  \newenvironment{partx}
    {%
      \noindent
      % some stuff goes here
      \ignorespaces
    }
    {%
      % some other stuff goes here
    }
\fi

\begin{document}
\vspace*{.8\textheight}% forcing a page break if the below is breakable
\begin{partx}
  \blindduck
\end{partx}
\end{document}
```

Another possibility would be to define the environment only once but with branching in the definition. The tests would have to be done every time the environment is used, but you could easily change midway. The definition would then look like the following:

```
\newcommand\ifdoctype[1]
  {%
    \ifdefstring{\doctype}{#1}%
  }
\newenvironment{partx}
  {%
    \noindent
    \ifdoctype{unbrokenpartx}{\minipage{\textwidth}}{}%
    % some stuff goes here
    \ignorespaces
  }
  {%
    % some other stuff goes here
    \ifdoctype{unbrokenpartx}{\endminipage}{}%
  }
```

Note that I changed the definition of `\ifdoctype` as well, as the advantages of the `\ifdoctype...\fi` approach don't seem to apply as much here (the branching is done in stuff which is tokenized anyway).